# Finding $\lim_{z\to i} \frac{\arctan(1+z^2)^2}{\sin^2(1+z^2)}$ without using Taylor expansions

Tags: limits

I'm stuck trying to compute this limit: 
$$\lim_{z\to i}  \frac{\arctan(1+z^2)^2}{\sin^2(1+z^2)}$$

I tried to use the logarithm form of $\arctan$ and the exponential form of $\sin$ but the formula got too complicated.

Comment: Could you use L'Hopital?

Comment: In numerator, what is squared ? The argument or the function ?

Comment: @garserdt216  yes, how could I not have thought about trying l'hospital rule

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici the argument

Comment: @1.2.3 *Are you allowed

Comment: @garserdt216 it is only said that the use of taylor expansions is not allowed so I guess yes I am

Comment: A reflexion on this limitation : we are allowed to say $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 1$ but not $\sin x = x+o(x)$... Next time, let's find the limit without using any mathematical tool.

Comment: @zwim: are we allowed $\sin x:=1/2i \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+ix/n)^n-(1-ix/n)^n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust upvoted comment, because it brought me a large smile. :-)

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{z\to i}  \frac{\arctan(1+z^2)^2}{\sin^2(1+z^2)}=\lim_{w\to 0}  \frac{\dfrac{\arctan w^2}{w^2}}{\dfrac{\sin^2 w}{w^2}}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(z^2+1\right)^2}{\sin^2 \left(z^2+1\right)}=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(z^2+1\right)^2}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}\times \left(\frac{{\left(z^2+1\right)}}{\sin \left(z^2+1\right)}\right)^2$$ should help.

Comment: Hi Claude. You were the fastest, again ;-)